# Removing elements from list based on condition

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, hashmap, filtering

I have a code that selectively adds data to a map like the following,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
                new Person("Johnny", "Depp", 18),
                new Person("Jennifer", null, 30),
                new Person("Angelina", null, 23),
                new Person("Angelina", "Garlic", 38),
                new Person("Angelina", "Jolie", 40),
        );

        Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (Person person:
             people) {
            Person temp = map.get(person.getFirstName());
            if(temp == null || temp.getLastName() == null)
                map.put(person.getFirstName(), person);
        }

        for (Map.Entry mapper:
             map.entrySet()) {
            Person temp = (Person) mapper.getValue();
            System.out.println(temp.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(temp.getLastName());
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Person.java contains the following:

```
public class Person {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Now, I need to check the following conditions,
1) is the map has multiple records with the same firstname; and if the record has a null as last name, then it should add this record to the map.
2) If the map has only one records for a person's firstname; and if that record has a null as last name, then it qualifies to be added to the map.

**So the output I get for my current solution is,**

Johnny
Depp

Jennifer
null

Angelina
Garlic

**Where as my required output should be,**

Johnny
Depp

Jennifer
null

Angelina
Garlic

Angelina
Jolie

**NOTE : I am making use of Java 7 (no, java 8 is not an option)**

Comment: I think you mean that if there are multiple records with the samme first name and one has null last name, then it should *not* be added?

Comment: I don't understand the title of this question. What does it have to do with removing elements from a list based on a condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because, in a Map, the key has to be unique so when you check the second time for Angelina and it matches because the last name is `null` and you put into the map you override the original Angelina. [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) have to have unique keys,

> public interface Map
>   An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

## I found two different ways of solving it

**1. Use a supplementary list to maintain the objects that will override the current keys**

```
List<Person> supplementaryList = new ArrayList<Person>();

Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<String, Person>();

for (Person person : people) {

  Person temp = map.get(person.getFirstName());

  if (temp != null) {
    supplementaryList.add(person);
    if (temp.getLastName() == null)
      map.remove(temp.getFirstName());

  } else {
    map.put(person.getFirstName(), person);
  }
}

for (Map.Entry mapper : map.entrySet()) {
  Person temp = (Person) mapper.getValue();
  System.out.println(temp.getFirstName());
  System.out.println(temp.getLastName());
  System.out.println();
}

for (Person p : supplementaryList) {

  System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + p.getLastName());

}
```

**2. With `Map<String,List<Person>>`**

```
Map<String, List<Person>> namesMap = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();

for (Person p : people) {

  List<Person> res = namesMap.get(p.getFirstName());

  // if there is not valid list of names for key add new person
  if (res == null) {
    List<Person> newListOfPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
    newListOfPeople.add(p);
    namesMap.put(p.getFirstName(), newListOfPeople);
  } else {

    if (p.getLastName() != null) {
      res.add(p);
      namesMap.put(p.getFirstName(), res);
      Iterator<Person> iter = res.iterator();
      // remove null from list if it exists
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Person person = iter.next();
        if (person.getLastName() == null)
          iter.remove();
      }
    }
  }
}

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Person>> kv : namesMap.entrySet()) {
  if (kv.getValue() != null) {
    for (Person p : kv.getValue())
      System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName());

  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Johnny Depp
Jennifer null
Angelina Garlic
Angelina Jolie
```

Comment: yes, I tried this approach earlier but found the design not so elegant since it used two data structures and then looping through them individually. Although I cannot think of any other approach, thanks for the solution! Up voted!

Comment: @PewDiePie I added the implementation for the way that was mentioned below with `Map<String, List<Person>> ` . Thanks for the upvote, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

HashMap doesn't allow duplicate keys (firstName), so you can't see Angelina Jolie in your Map.
From the documentation of java HashMap.

> public V put(K key,
>       V value)
>   Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

So I recommend to you two approaches in order to solve your problem:

1. Make a `Map<String,List<Person>>` so here the key is the firstName and List is every person that must your requirements.
2. Use an implementation that support multikey, like Multimap of Apache Commons Collections, or from Guava.

Comment: I think the first approach would require a lot of conditions again, especially while checking if the key isn't already there in the map, then create a new arraylist and then add it to the map associated with the key.
Although, I was thinking of the second approach, but I havent used multi maps before, if you could throw some light on it (would really help me). Also, if you could suggest an alternate approach and not using maps at all

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do it in two passes.

In the first pass, only put records with a non-null last name in a temporary map. Never mind that duplicate first names will get lost for now.

Before the second pass, create a result collection, either set or list. Map won't do. In the second pass, for each record with null lastname, you can check in the map whether any record exists with the same first name and a non-null last name. Now you know which records should go into your result.

Instead of the temporary map a set of first names is really enough.